# Filtering results of Mysql Variance

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a report where we are monitoring fuel levels in tanks, and trying to get a list of those tanks that haven't had a change over a certain period of time.

```
SELECT  VARIANCE(GallonsInTank) Variance
     , TankID
     , AccountNumber 
  FROM Tanks
 WHERE RecordDate BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-12' 
 GROUP 
    BY TankID 
 ORDER 
    BY Variance DESC
```

I think I'm on the right track here, but I don't know how to say only show results with a variance of 0.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a Having clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Honeyboy Wilson stated, a `HAVING` clause should solve your problem. This will return only `TankID`, `AccountNumber` combinations "having" a variance of zero.

```
SELECT  VARIANCE(GallonsInTank) AS Variance, 
        TankID, 
        AccountNumber 
FROM `Tanks` 
WHERE `RecordDate` BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-12' 
GROUP BY TankID, AccountNumber
HAVING VARIANCE(GallonsInTank) = 0
```

Side note: You had left out `AccountNumber` from your GROUP BY statement.